# Accessing documents packaged in a jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar, filepath

Im trying to get the file path of a document that is packaged as a resource in a jar file so that i can display it in a swing application.  The way I have it now works when I run it from eclipse but if I export it to a runnable jar file I can't access the the documents that are packaged in the jar file.  How can I get the file path of the document when its inside the jar file?

Here is the line of code showing how I am trying to access the document:

```
File document = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/documents/document.pdf").getPath());
```

Comment: Have you checked that `document.pdf` is inside the jar at that location?

Comment: Yes its there.  I modified to code to use URL instead of file and if works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only kind of "file path" that exists for something inside a JAR file is the path relative to the root of the JAR. But in your case it seems that you know it already (it's "/resources/documents/document.pdf"). Files inside a JAR file have no path that you can use to access them directly as they don't exist within the real file system. You need to use either getResource() or getResourceAsStream() to access them. I don't remember right now which classes are used for images in Swing, but look closely at those classes - they should have overloaded methods that accept something like InputStream or URL instead of file path.

Comment: I used getResourceAsStream().  Thanks!